# Using SQL to insert between tables with repeating data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-update

My data is structured as follows:

```
Table 1 - Employee</b>

-ID
-Name
-Address
-City
-State
...

Table 2 - Audit

-Address
-City
-State
...
```

I need to **insert the corresponding id** from the employee table **into the audit table by** matching the **address, city, and state** from the smaller audit table with address information from the larger employee table (with the assumption that no employees share an address)

Here is the code I have been working with, the query generates the data that I want, but the update, set sequence fails with the following message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
UPDATE AuditTable SET employee_id = (
    SELECT e.employee_id 
    FROM EmployeeTable e 
    JOIN AuditTable a
        ON  e.address = a.address
        AND e.home_city = a.home_city
        AND e.home_st = a.home_st
)
```

The same employee needs to be able to repeat multiple times within the audit table and still show the same id, which is causing my problems. I already tried substituting ***=*** for ***IN*** and using ***TOP 1*** in my select statement but had no luck getting what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is that the subquery is not *correlated* with the table being updated, hence it generates multiple records.

If there are no duplicates for `(address, home_city, home_st)` tuples in the `Employee` table, then you can use a simple correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE AuditTable SET employee_id = (
    SELECT e.employee_id 
    FROM EmployeeTable e 
    WHERE 
        e.address = AuditTable.address 
        AND e.home_city = AuditTable.home_city 
        AND e.home_st = AuditTable.home_st
)
```

If duplicates may happen, then you can use `TOP 1` or an aggregate function such as `MAX()`:

```
UPDATE AuditTable SET employee_id = (
    SELECT TOP 1 e.employee_id 
    FROM EmployeeTable e 
    WHERE 
        e.address = AuditTable.address 
        AND e.home_city = AuditTable.home_city 
        AND e.home_st = AuditTable.home_st
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a join:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.employee_id = e.employee_id
FROM AuditTable a INNER JOIN EmployeeTable e 
ON e.address = a.address AND e.home_city = a.home_city AND e.home_st = a.home_st
```